# Are "adults-only" hotels the same as love motels?

Tags: japan, hotels

Arranging lodging for a trip to Japan with a friend (we're not dating). I have no issue with love motels in general, but I've never seen one with more than 1 bed per room. I'm looking for hotel rooms with 2 or more beds per room. It would be helpful if I didn't have to look at each "adult-only" hotel room to see if they'd meet our needs.

When looking at sites like Hotels.com or Booking.com, are hotels with an "adults-only" tag/label the same as love motels, which typically have only 1 (large) bed per room and frequently rent rooms for 2-3 hours in addition to overnight? Or are "adult-only" hotels simply hotels that don't allow children to stay there?

Comment: What is the actual name (in Japanese) of the kind of hotel you are looking for? Technically, all hotels are adult hotels, since I doubt minors could book one. Do you mean a hotel that doesn't allow children?

Comment: Where are you looking?  Likely a website that offers online booking of love hotels, might have a different definition of an "adult-only" hotel than say Agoda or Booking.com.

Comment: As a rule, love hotels don't show up in general-purpose English-language booking sites for Japan.  But the easiest way to find rooms with two beds would be to simply filter your search to twin beds only.

Comment: @user3169 "Technically, all hotels are adult hotels, since I doubt minors could book one." But most hotels allow children as guests, when accompanied by adults. The question seems perfectly reasonable; you seem to be complaining that the asker doesn't know what "adult-only hotel room" means, but that's exactly what their question is!

Comment: I have never ever encountered the term "adult-only hotel" so voting to close as unclear. If you mean that your booking site says somewhere that the hotel admits adult guests only, then you should say that.

Comment: It's quite common for resorts to be adults-only or no-children-allowed but not to be "love hotels". I can't speak to Japan specifically.

Comment: You may find it easier to get answers when you refer to them as love HOTELS not motels (although you are correct in the word usage) as in Japanese they are almost exclusively referred to as hotels.

Comment: @fkraiem I'm sorry but just because you don't know what an adult-only hotel is, it doesn't mean the question is unclear. It is a hotel that only allows adults. Here's a link to a random one in Majorca https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g580312-d573632-Reviews-Hotel_Astoria_Playa_Only_Adults-Port_d_Alcudia_Alcudia_Majorca_Balearic_Islands.html

Comment: OP, they are not the same. Adult-only hotels are simply that, hotels which only allow adults. A reason to book such a hotel is to not be bothered by children. It has nothing to do with adult activities.

Comment: @Belle This question is about Japan.

Comment: For that matter, "the same as love motels" is also arguably unclear. What exactly does OP mean by that? If the question is "Do such hotels necessarily contain only one bed per room?", then it should say that.

Comment: @fkraiem A "love hotel" (or motel) is a hotel designed exclusively to be a convenient place for its guests to have sex. You generally do not book them in advance but rather turn up with your partner(s) when the mood takes you. Typically you meet someone in a bar and rather than go back to your own place which in Japan may be too small to accommodate guests, you can make use of a love hotel. There are no other amenities provided that you would expect from other hotels; and love hotels often sell rooms by the hour instead of overnight.

Comment: @fkraiem Just to add to Calchas' comment: Love motels in Korea usually offer condoms, lube, and vaginal hygiene products either upon check-in nor in the room, as well as combs/brushes, hairspray, and hair gel in the room, in addition to the regular toiletries supplied by mainstream hotels--Everything you'd need to go home/to work/back out in public after a tryst. I've even stayed in some that could supply me with a companion (for an additional fee) if I so desired.

Comment: Meanwhile, if the question is "What do booking.com et al. mean by 'adult-only hotel'", maybe asking them would be best...

Answer (score 8):

I have been to some Hotels in Japan, that were tagged Adult only and not Love Hotels. A lot of traditional hotels (Ryokan) have this tag as well, and you get separate foutons, aswell as dinner and breakfast included.

Most of the Love Hotels do not show up on popular booking sites, and when they do, they are a lot more expensive than the walk-in price.